# ServiceStack - How To Compress Requests From Client

Tags: compression, servicestack, gzip

Does anyone have any examples of how to setup ServiceStack on the client side to automatically compress all *requests* using GZip?  I've found good examples of how to automatically decompress requests on the server side using a Module but nothing for the client side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/d47373d9ad3d603dedbee879e3a1c07330fcf4bc) automatically sends the `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` HTTP Header indicating it accepts a GZip or Deflated response. It can be disabled with:

```
client.DisableAutoCompression = true;
```

If the Web Server returns a compressed response indicated with the `Content-Encoding` HTTP Response header the Service Client transparently decompresses it.

Support for client Gzip + Deflate compression has also been added to ServiceStack Server and all C# Service Clients in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/d47373d9ad3d603dedbee879e3a1c07330fcf4bc).

This lets you send client requests with the new `RequestCompressionType` property, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl)
{
    RequestCompressionType = CompressionTypes.GZip,
};

var response = client.Post(new NameOfDto { ... });
```

This feature is available from v4.5.5+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks mythz!  That's exactly what I was looking for. Originally my thought was to compress all requests but by subclassing JsonServiceClient I can only implement it on the calls that I really need it for.