# Servicestack client compression fails with generic lists

Tags: servicestack

This question is a follow-up to
[ServiceStack client compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428857/servicestack-client-compression/41447014)

Servicestack natively supports client gzip/deflate compression since v4.5.5

But when I use a DTO with a property that is a generic list, that will will always be null when it reaches the service. Example below is a modded Servicestack unit-test which reproduces the issue:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

using Funq;

using NUnit.Framework;

using ServiceStack;

[TestFixture]
public class ServiceStackTest
{
    private readonly ServiceStackHost appHost;

    public ServiceStackTest()
    {
        appHost = new AppHost().Init().Start("http://localhost:8105/");
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_send_GZip_client_request()
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:8105/") { RequestCompressionType = CompressionTypes.GZip, };
        var hello = new Hello { Name = "GZIP", Test = new List<string> { "Test" } };

        // "Hello" has valid Test-list with one value
        var response = client.Post(hello);
        Assert.That(response.Result, Is.EqualTo("Hello, GZIP (1)"));
    }

    class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public AppHost()
            : base(nameof(ServiceStackTest), typeof(HelloService).GetAssembly())
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
[Route("/hello")]
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Test { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class HelloResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : IService
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        // "Hello" has null request.Test
        return new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name} ({request.Test?.Count})" };
    }
}
```

Is there a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should now be resolved with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1c2ff84e5768b1ed549aae647c907cbb299ee4d7) which now works as expected:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl)
{
    RequestCompressionType = CompressionTypes.GZip,
};
var response = client.Post(new HelloGzip
{
    Name = "GZIP",
    Test = new List<string> { "Test" }
});
response.Result //= Hello, GZIP (1)
```

This fix is now available from v4.5.5+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget), if you have an existing v4.5.5+ installed you'll need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages).

Comment: Cleared all caches but still doesn't work. I will wait for the next interim release and try again.

Comment: @MartinA it should work with latest version on MyGet after clearing your NuGet cache, waiting till next release should have the same behavior. If you can put together a small stand-alone example (e.g on Github) I can make sure any other issues are resolved before next release.

Comment: OK, so we have a nuget proxy cache server, which didn't update to the "latest" 4.5.5. It does work now!